# Aligning vector elements to rows of matrix (vertical alignment) in matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: vertical-alignment, matrices, vector

When the matrix is complex and the vector is simple, the output does not look good:

Code:

```
\begin{bmatrix}
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^M{(x_i)^2} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^M{(x_i)} \\
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^M{(x_i)} & M
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
m \\ c
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^M{(x_i y_i)} \\
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^M{(y_i)}
\end{bmatrix}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

In the desired output, the brackets of the vector should have the same size as that of the matrix, and the elements of the vector should align with the row of the matrix, which looks like this:

Desired output (this was produced by editing the above image):

[image]

What should I do to get the desired output **without complex layout commands**? A solution that could work inside the TeX mode (`$$`) on [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io) is preferred.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

I think the central problem with your equation is not that the column vector looks puny next to the matrices, but that you're using `\displaystyle` (and, implicitly) `\limits` *inside* the matrices. Speacking for myself, creating super-tall column vectors -- as you do in your screenshot and as is done in the first solution shown below -- does not good at all. In fact, it's just preposterous.

Switching from implicit `\limits` to explicit `\nolimits` of summation -- see the second solution below -- creates a modest visual improvement. However, in my opionion, the column vector still looks much too tall.

What you should really be thinking about is (a) not using `\displaystyle` at all, (b) simplifying the terms in the limits of summation (to show just the index of summation), and (c) reducing the visual clutter by omitting the unnecessary parentheses around the terms `x_i^2`, `x_i`, `y_i`, and `x_iy_i`; the outcome of this approach is shown in third solution below. Observe that the height of the column vector is automatically equal to the height of the matrices -- no additional fiddling required!

Incidentally, if your readers aren't already fully aware of the fact that the summation runs from `i=1` to `i=M`, you simply *must* inform them about this  *before* they start seeing lots and lot of summation expressions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'bmatrix' and 'gather*' environments
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\addlinespace' macro
%% Define two typographic struts:
\newcommand\tallstrut{\vphantom{\displaystyle\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^M}}
\newcommand\reallytallstrut{\vphantom{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^M}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
%% First solution: use \displaystyle and \limits (as in the OP's query)
\begin{bmatrix}
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^M{(x_i)^2} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^M{(x_i)} \\ \addlinespace
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^M{(x_i)} & M
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
m\reallytallstrut \\ \addlinespace c\reallytallstrut
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^M{(x_i y_i)} \\ \addlinespace
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^M{(y_i)}
\end{bmatrix}\\[2ex]
%% Second solution: use \displaystyle and \nolimits
\begin{bmatrix}
\displaystyle\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^M{(x_i)^2} & \displaystyle\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^M{(x_i)} \\ \addlinespace
\displaystyle\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^M{(x_i)} & M
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
m\tallstrut \\ \addlinespace c\tallstrut
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\displaystyle\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^M{(x_i y_i)} \\ \addlinespace
\displaystyle\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^M{(y_i)}
\end{bmatrix}\\[2ex]
%% Third solution: use \textstyle (and \nolimits)
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_i x_i^2 & \sum_i x_i \\ \addlinespace
\sum_i x_i & M
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
m \\ \addlinespace c
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_i x_i y_i \\ \addlinespace
\sum_i y_i
\end{bmatrix}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried the first solution and that is what I preferred. It works very well in StackEdit! In my version, I did not use `\addlinespace` (it does not seem to work in StackEdit), and I did not use `\newcommand` (I put the expanded version in `\vphantom`). Now I know how to use `\vphantom` too! Thank you so much!

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji- - Glad you liked learning about `\vphantom`. :-)